# Admin.sites.url password transmission

Tags: python, django

When you login to django, does the password get hashed and then transmitted or is it transmitted in the clear and the server does the hashing?

This is within the context of not using https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sent in the clear, then the server hashes it. You would need to use https to prevent eavesdropping.

Comment: You could do your own client-side hashing but to do so securely would be quite difficult. Why reinvent the wheel? You can get a free SSL cert recognized by all major browsers from [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/).